# How to map <D-A> to increment 1 in MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim

How do I get the increment by 1 behavior in MacVim for Command-A?  `<C-A>` increments as excpected. In windows I just have to unmap `<C-A>`, so in MacVim I've tried the following:

```
" Doesn't seem to work. <D-A> still selects all
macmenu Edit.Select\ All key=<Nop>
nnoremap <D-A> <C-A>
```

_

```
" Doesn't work, no mapping exists
nunmap <D-A>
```

I've looked at the following, but I still can't figure it out:

[how to map command key when configurate .vimrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528151/how-to-map-command-key-when-configurate-vimrc)

[How to increment in vim under windows (where CTRL-A does not work...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919/how-to-increment-in-vim-under-windows-where-ctrl-a-does-not-work)

Comment: You don't have a Control key on your Mac?

Comment: Yeah, mentions it in the question. I prefer the command key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in `:help :macmenu`,

- you must do that in `~/.gvimrc`,
- `<D-..>` mappings are case sensitive so `<D-A>` is not the same as `<D-a>`.

So, in order to use `<D-a>` in place of `<C-a>`:

1. Create `~/.gvimrc` if it doesn't exist.
2. Add the following lines:

   ```
   macmenu Edit.Select\ All key=<nop>
   nnoremap <D-a> <C-a>
   ```

Comment: That did the trick. I had made the false assumption that putting things in the `.gvimrc` was just a convention and didn't make a difference. That's what I get for assuming. Thanks for your help.